# How to use Vim-like registers across programs

Tags: vim, clipboard

I'd like to be able to `dd j dd` in Vim, then `p "2p` in a text box on
another program.

The ideal solution would allow Vim yank and put bindings across the OS.

I'm using Arch Linux with DWM as my window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Register `+` is supposed to be connected to the system clipboard, so you can also use it to transfer between two independent instances of `vim`.

Having only one clipboard, you would need to combine your clips; for your example: `dd j p k "+2dd` to cut those separate lines into on and paste them with `"+p" in the other` vim` instance.